# Exporting Hbase scan command output as CSV/Pipeseperated

Tags: hbase

I am looking for a way to export output of a scan command from Hbase.

```
hbase(main):028:0* scan 'version_test_2',{FILTER => "MultipleColumnPrefixFilter('name','sal')",TIMERANGE => [0, 2] }
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
 1                                          column=cf:name, timestamp=1, value=dijin
 2                                          column=cf:name, timestamp=1, value=vaibhav
 3                                          column=cf:name, timestamp=1, value=ram
 4                                          column=cf:name, timestamp=1, value=jana
 5                                          column=cf:name, timestamp=1, value=anand
```

Trying to export the output as CSV file.Is there any way to get this done??

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Dijin.